# Using Boto3 to create loop on specific folder

Tags: python, boto3

I am testing the new data feeds as in XML. Those data will be stored in S3 in the following format:

2018\1\2\1.xml
2018\1\3\1.xml
2018\1\3\2.xml

etc.  So, multiple .xml files are possible on one day.  Also, important to note that there are folders in this bucket that I do NOT want to pull.  So I have to target a very specific directory.

There is no date time stamp within the file, so I need to use created, modified, something to go off of.  To do this I think of using a dictionary of key, values with folder+xml file as the key, created/modified timestamp as the value. Then, use that dict to essentially re-pull all the objects.

Here's what I've tried..

i

```
mport boto3
from pprint import pprint

client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
result = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket='bucket',
    Prefix='folder/folder1/folder2')

bucket_object_list = []
for page in result:
    pprint(page)
    if "Contents" in page:
        for key in page[ "Contents" ]:
            keyString = key[ "Key" ]
            pprint(keyString)
            bucket_object_list.append(keyString)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('bucket','bucket_object_list')
obj.get()["Contents"].read().decode('utf-8')

pprint(obj.get())
sys.exit()
```

This is throwing an error from the key within the obj = s3.Object('cluster','key') line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3test2.py", line 25, in <module>
    obj = s3.Object('cluster', key)
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

The Maxitems is purely for testing purposes although it's interesting since this translates to 1000 when run.

Comment: First, s3 is not a "file system", the "folder name" is arbitrary and is part of the object key.  It is using "prefix" filter to select similar arbitrary "folder name".  Second, you can store some meta information inside s3 object "meta".
Lastly,  always copy the exception error (even from your code somebody may already know the coding mistake))

Comment: When you do this `obj = s3.Object('cluster', key)`, do you have a bucket call "cluster" ? And where is your key derived from ?

Comment: I get that it's not a file system but AWS docs state you should be able to use the prefixes in order to get to the "folders" you want keys for.

No bucket is named cluster, I was just using arbitrary names and for some reason didn't use the "ABucket" name form farther up.

My intentions on the second part of the code was to pull the exact keys the paginator was grabbing.  I could be completely off-base here, I'm a SaS.

I added the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

As far as error is concerned, it's because key is not defined.

From [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) documentation:

> **Object(bucket_name, key)**
>
> Creates a Object resource.:
>
> object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')
>
> **Parameters**
>
> bucket_name(string) -- The Object's bucket_name identifier. This must be set.
>
> key(string) -- The Object's key identifier. This must be set.

**You need to assign an object key name to the 'key' you're using in the code**

**The keyName is the "name" (=unique identifier) by which your file will be stored in the S3 bucket**

Code based on what you posted:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3') 
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2') 
result = paginator.paginate( Bucket='bucket_name', Prefix='folder/folder1/folder2') 
bucket_object_list = [] 
for page in result:  
    if "Contents" in page: 
        for key in page[ "Contents" ]: 
            keyString = key[ "Key" ] 
            print(keyString) 
            bucket_object_list.append(keyString) 

print bucket_object_list

s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
for file_name in bucket_object_list:
    obj = s3.Object('bucket_name',file_name) 
    print(obj.get())
    print(obj.get()["Body"].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Yeah I just set a bucket_object_list =[] at the top of the loop that I want to fill with the keys.

I think my larger issue I'm seeing is when I run the Paginator, I'm not seeing any contents, etc.  It's almost as if it's grabbing no keys(even though I know objects exist).  I updated the code above.

Comment: Got it.   Got some new errors but I think that's more to do with special characters in my objects rather than code

Comment: Yes, this code works with bucket and files I've without any errors. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines) to debug the error you mentioned